# how to add a parameter to soap body in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, servicecontract

Our clients want to use the following soap message to call my WCF Service:

```
<soapenv:Envelope .....>
<soapenv:Header />
<soapenv:Body>
  <st:myExtraParam>str ex</st:myExtraParam>
  <st:MyMethod>
    <st:myfuncParam>func str</st:myfuncParam> 
  </st:MyMethod>
  ....
  ....
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I created my service contract like the following:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
   [OperationContractAttribute]
   public ResponseObj MyMethod(string myfuncParam)
}
```

Now, how can I enable `<st:myExtraParam>param str</st:myExtraParam>` parameter above the function tag?

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct was to say that one can't have more than one direct child element of the SOAP Body element. But [the SOAP specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#soapbody) says that it's fine to do so.

I don't think that WCF, based on [ServiceContract], can do it, though.

Comment: Because SOAP specification says that we can use more than one child under SOAP Body element, I cannot force my client not to use the XML described on my question. So I am still trying to make a solution.